# my output says only: Y=-nan for so many times

Tags: segmentation-fault, geometry, logic, nan, ellipse

Hi I write a code which gives the coordinate of y-coordinates of y

this is my struct:

typedef struct polyline:

```
{double x,y;
}pline2d;
```

and this is my function:

```
//cen =center wh ->x=width and wh->y =height

void draw_ellipse(pline2d * cen, pline2d * wh)
{
    printf("Enter the center coordinates:\nX:");    scanf("%lf",&cen->x);
    printf("Y:");                                   scanf("%lf",&cen->y);
    printf("Enter width:");                         scanf("%lf",&wh->x);
    printf("Enter height:");                        scanf("%lf",&wh->y);
    double aps=-(wh->x)/2;
    while (aps<=(wh->x)/2)
    {
        double resx,resy;
        resy=wh->y*sqrt(1-((aps-cen->x)*(aps-cen->x))/(wh->x*wh->x))+cen->y;
        printf("y=%lf\n",resy);
        aps+=0.1;
    }
}
```

and it only gives

> Y=-nan

output what should I do?

Comment: I advise to break the long formula into small pieces. Print them before calculation, so as to see what's happening.

Comment: `NAN` is usualy a result of  `sqrt (-constant)`  so when you enter wrong values you might got negative subresults under sqrt ... What language is this C/C++/other ? add tag